# Z-index Find the stacking context of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

How do I find the stacking context of an element?
Or, how do I find that element's ancestor element which is controlling the `z-index` of the descendant?

I have a very complex page with nested tables, divs. And an absolutely positioned box with a high `z-index` is hidden.

I have fixed these problems before by methodically working my way through the element's ancestors until I find where to add a `z-index` value and position value to create a new stacking context.

But I can't seem to solve it that way for this problem.

Is there a tool, (either in a browser's developer tools, or in Javascript) where I can give it element `A`, and it returns something like :

> "element A is part of stacking context beginning at element B, which
>   is part of the stacking context beginning at element C, which is part
>   of the root stacking context of the page"

Help me guys, you're my only hope.

Comment: I don't know about any specific tool, but this might help with understanding(although I see you probably understand it already): http://www.cssmojo.com/extras/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask/

Comment: In the inspect element (Chrome dev tool), below everything you have selected element 'tree' where you can see all parents from selected element until <html>. Will that work?

Comment: As @Arcagully stated, You can use Chrome to inspect elements, alternatives include firefox, internet explorer and the "web developer" plugin for many browsers.

Comment: To extend what @doveyg suggests: Have you tried the 3D view? In Firefox:
Open Developer Tools (not Firebug) and open the options (little gear on the top-right), scroll down to "3D Inspection". A cube will appear on the top-right side. Click it.
Z-Index elements will be shown as hovering above the rest. It does not straight up show the context, but it really helps in visualizing which element is the "mother-z-index element".

Comment: 3D view in Firefox looks cool but it's pretty useless for this sort of thing.  zvisualiser (below from potatopeelings) was kind of what I was looking for

Comment: this is perhaps a duplicate of [is-there-a-way-to-see-the-stacking-context-in-ie-firefox-chrome-etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800511/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-stacking-context-in-ie-firefox-chrome-etc)

Comment: and the accepted answer suggests using the [z-context](https://github.com/gwwar/z-context) Chrome extension

Answer (score 2):

McNulty, the tool you are looking for is a Chrome extension called "z-context" by Github user gwwar. I am working on a very complicated grid component which has lots of nested divs in the DOM structure and I needed something that would help.

I have used the extension and can confirm it works as of the date of this posting. Make sure to open a new browser session after you install it.

https://github.com/gwwar/z-context

Comment: I've been using this extension very successfully -- unfortunately it's recently stopped working.  Chrome 92.

Comment: What exactly is not working @ukrutt ? It works for me in Chrome 104

Comment: @DanielTuruș I don't remember exactly; I think the contents of the stacking contexts pane/module didn't show up. It works well for me now (also on Chrome 104)